# blazor webassembly validation does not block 2nd submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

We have two buttons inside of an Editform. They do a bit of different things. But we want the Data annotation validation to work on both button click. The first button is easy, it triggers the `OnValidSubmit`. But the second button, although it triggers page validation, still writes to console.

Below is the class used:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyApp.Client.Models
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string MyName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Below is the razor component which includes two buttons and one inputtext field:

```
@page "/test"

<h3>test</h3>

<EditForm Model="model" OnValidSubmit="PostAsync" class="mt-5">

    <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
    <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>

    <div class="row w-100">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="float-lg-right row">
            <div class="col-6 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-black w-100">Save</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-black w-100" @onclick="(async ()=>await SaveAndGoToListAsync())">Save &amp; Go To List</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <label for="MyName" class="col-form-label">My Name:</label>
        <InputText id="MyName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="model.MyName"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>model.MyName)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>

    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private TestModel model;
public Test()
{
    model = new();
}

private void PostAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("PostAsync");
}

private async Task SaveAndGoToListAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("SaveAndGoToListAsync");    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the second button has an `onclick` method.

```
@onclick="(async ()=>await SaveAndGoToListAsync())"
```

Here, instead of `OnValidSubmit`, you should use Context and Anonymous Functions, you can call the methods related to `onclick`s and pass the `formContext` to them. For validation, you can check the validity of the form for the corresponding method using `Context.Validate` in the corresponding method.

```
@page "/test"

<h3>test</h3>

<EditForm Model="model" Context="formContext" class="mt-5">

    <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
    <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>

    <div class="row w-100">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="float-lg-right row">
                <div class="col-6 text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-black w-100" @onclick="(()=>PostAsync(formContext))">Save</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-black w-100" @onclick="(async ()=>await SaveAndGoToListAsync(formContext))">Save &amp; Go To List</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="MyName" class="col-form-label">My Name:</label>
            <InputText id="MyName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="model.MyName"></InputText>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>model.MyName)"></ValidationMessage>
        </div>

    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private TestModel model;
    public Test()
    {
        model = new();
    }

    private void PostAsync(EditContext formContext)
    {
        bool formIsValid = formContext.Validate();
        if (formIsValid == false)
            return;

        Console.WriteLine("PostAsync");
    }

    private async Task SaveAndGoToListAsync(EditContext formContext)
    {
        bool formIsValid = formContext.Validate();
        if (formIsValid == false)
            return;

        Console.WriteLine("SaveAndGoToListAsync");    
    }
}
```